# Go language Query column referencing not working

Tags: sql, database, go

I have a query in GO that returns a different response from mysql.

here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        questions.id as question_id, 
        questions.question, 
        questions.priority, 
        questions.type
    FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.user_id = ? 
    LEFT JOIN group ON group.user_id = profile.user_id  
    WHERE questions.status = 1 
    AND group.status = 1 
    AND questions.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = profiles.user_id)
```

When I run this on mysql terminal it returns nothing as expected. But when I try to run this on GO lang it has a return which is not supposed to be returned since it has already been filtered in the NOT IN clause which are all the answered questions. When I tried to change the profiles.user_id to a specific value it returns the expected output.

I think the use of column parameters in not working in GO. It will be a quick fix if I change the users.profile to a specific variable but there are other queries that needs to use that feature in order to achieve my expected output.

I tried using stmt.Prepared statement and the db.Query() with same results

Go code:

```
query :=    "    SELECT DISTINCT " +
        "        questions.id as question_id, " +
        "        questions.question, " +
        "        questions.priority, " +
        "        questions.type " +
        "    FROM questions " +
        "    LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.user_id = 1627 " +
        "    LEFT JOIN group ON group.user_id = profile.user_id  " +
        "    WHERE questions.status = 1 " +
        "    AND group.status = 1 " +
        "    AND questions.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = profiles.user_id); "

stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
if err != nil {
    checkErr(err) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
}
defer stmt.Close() // Close the statement when we leave main() / the program terminates

userId := json.userId

args := []interface{}{}
args = append(args, userId)

start := time.Now()
rows, err := stmt.Query(args...)
elapsed := time.Since(start)

if err != nil {
    checkErr(err) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
}

// Fetch rows
for rows.Next() {
    // get RawBytes from data
    err = rows.Scan(&question.QuestionId, &question.Question, &question.Priority, &question.Type)
    questions = append(questions, question)
    if err != nil {
        checkErr(err) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }
}
defer rows.Close()
defer db.Close()
```

Is there any workaround for it to work ?

Thanks for your response

Comment: Please show code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use question mark '?' in the query in places where you expect a parameter:

```
age := 27
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
        var name string
        if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Also, you can use back tick ` for a multi-line string in your code (rather than concatenation with +). It would make your code easier to read.

```
query :=    `SELECT DISTINCT
    questions.id as question_id, 
    questions.question, 
    questions.priority, 
    questions.type 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.user_id = 1627 
LEFT JOIN group ON group.user_id = profile.user_id  
WHERE questions.status = 1 
AND group.status = 1 
AND questions.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = profiles.user_id); `
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem I am having is that referencing a left join column for where clause is not working.

Comment: I understand but I don’t see any reference to parameters in your query string.

Comment: (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = profiles.user_id) in this statement I used the profile user_id

Comment: @banri16 you said "When I tried to change the profiles.user_id to a specific value it returns the expected output." it seems clear to me that the problem is in passing the parameter, not the query itself. You need a question mark instead of 1627

Comment: yes, but I am trying to use the column I joined from profiles. I will be using this query to other function as well so I am trying to figure out why column referencing is not working on Go but works properly on mysql commad.

Comment: There is no such thing as “column referencing is not working on Go”. You are misunderstanding what role each part is playing. Go is not running your query, MySql is. Either the SQL you are sending is correct or not. The behavior of MySql won’t change depending on the client. The client is only sending the query (in essence a string conforming to the SQL syntax) and fetching the result.

Comment: I tried the same query in mysql and it is working just fine. I also tried to log the query. I am still learning Go so I am really not sure what is wrong. I'm sorry If my question is confusing. But as I stated I tried the query on mysql terminal before coding it in GO.